# React Component keeps re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

In my page I am calling an action in my `useEffect` to populate my reducer. I have a component level state called `page` which is a parameter in the action. So every time the value of `page` changes I would like the action to be called again because obviously I intend to get the data from different pages.

Sadly I run into errors in the console telling me the component has reached its limit for times of re-rendering.

Here is the relevant code:

```
const Home = props => {

    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        props.getPopularMovies(page);
    }, [page])
```

My `props.getPopularMovies` function is coming from my `mapDispatchToProps` function which is being passed into `connect()`

Entire Home Page:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { connect } from "react-redux";

// Actions
import { getPopularMovies } from "../actions/movies.action";

const Home = (props) => {

    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        props.getPopularMovies(page);
    }, [page])

    return (
        <div>
            {props.movies && props.movies.length > 0 && props.movies.data.results.map(movie => (
                <p key={movie.id}>{movie.title}</p>
            ))}
            <button onClick={setPage(page + 1)}>Next Page</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        movies: state.movies.movies
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    getPopularMovies
})(Home)
```

Action File:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GET_MOVIES_FAIL, GET_MOVIES_SUCCESS } from "../constants/movies.constants"

export const getPopularMovies = (page) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const config = {
            params: {
                api_key: process.env.REACT_API_KEY,
                page
            
            }
        };

        const movies = await axios.get('/movie/popular', config);

        dispatch({
            type: GET_MOVIES_SUCCESS,
            payload: movies
        })
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_MOVIES_FAIL,
            payload: err
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Who is using `setPage`?

Comment: Please share code for getPopularMovies as well

Comment: I have updated the question to include more code :) @SiddharthS.

Comment: In the updated question you will see it is being used on a button click @Krasimir

Comment: @JaredSmith Don't quite understand, I understand it will run when `page` changes because it's in the dependency array, not sure what you mean in the second part.

Comment: Oops. Misread the code, I see people with that problem post the same question 500 times a day. Have a +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign the method setPage as an event handler to the onClick event, you are invoking it instead of assigning it. So, instead of this:

```js
<button onClick={setPage(page + 1)}>Next Page</button>
```

try this:

```js
<button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>Next Page</button>
```

Comment: That definitely did something, I can at least now see the button on the page however the list of movies doesn't appear from my map function. Despite being in my reducer

Comment: What is the structure of the data returned ... What is the value of props.movies.data.result? Are the results available here or at props.movies.map gets you the desired results...

Comment: When I refreshed the page it went back to blank. In the console it says cannot read properties of undefined, reading "results". But I thought the check I have before the map function should sort that :/

Comment: I got it, seemed I had to do a check for each level in the state, thank you!